# What is the php function for "user's public profile"

Tags: profiles

My header looks like this.

[image]

I chnaged my author base from "author" to "user"

So the user profile url looks like this.

http://example.com/user/username

What is the php function to get this url.

I'm using like this

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>user/<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>"><?php echo $current_user->user_login ?></a>
```

Its working. But its hard coded.

Is there any other php function to get the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all author meta details you can use `the_author_meta`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta

```
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url', $current_user->ID);?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name', $current_user->ID);?></a>
```

If its for user meta use `get_user_meta`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

```
<a href="<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_url');?>"><?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'display_name');?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you search for [`get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url)?

Note, you need the author ID, not the login name.